# Excel: Graphs which appear only conditionally

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have a rather complex data set and the first column is composed of Booleans.

I want to plot data from each row in a separate graph - but only if the first cell in that row is TRUE. Preferably, this would all happen automatically.

In other words, the sheet is prepared to plot each row always, but does so if and only if the first cell of that row is TRUE. Ideally, the graphs will be organized in a predetermined way, but that is less important to me.

How do I do this?

Comment: If the graphs just happen to be invisible (but nonetheless present), that is okay too.

Comment: Excel charts are objects, and you can set the ChartObject.Visible property programmatically.  So you could do this using VBA.  Try a search.  Here's [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936831/how-to-hide-a-chart-in-vba) with some minor problems that got sorted out, I think.

Comment: How do I use VBA?

Comment: That is kind of a *big* question.  You could [start here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=17&ved=0ahUKEwi95e7btLjaAhUQWqwKHQvBDyQQtwIIwAEwEA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DXY8tCF1qnOc&usg=AOvVaw3drnCtNmBjkvuuxhNLu7fD).

Comment: Wait, why is the original a bad question?

To Bandersnatch: Thanks for the link. I knew that it was a big question, but any good listing of resources is helpful.

Comment: Good luck.  VBA can be fun.  It can make you pull your hair out too, but I hope you find the fun part.

Comment: A downvote doesn't mean it's a *bad* question. Generally, people here expect questions to show that some work has been done trying to solve the problem, and not just outline the goal expecting a solution. I imagine you were just looking for guidance on where to start. And you have that now, so best of luck.

Comment: In addition to the previous feedback, you could create every chart and just not look at the ones you aren't interested in.  Adding the Boolean to the chart would identify which are relevant.  If that isn't adequate, it means there are more requirements that you haven't discussed, like output layout specs.

Comment: My previous plan was to produce each graph and then manually move the ones that I want to another sheet for ease of reference. The trouble with this is twofold: (1) There are going to be well over forty graphs, many of which are likely to be blank, each time that I go to use this document; (2) I would like the layout on the sheet with the nontrivial graphs to be regular, professional, and machine-made-looking. It seems that I shall be taking the VBA approach. :)